# The saddle point method for a real-value multivariate function with several minimal

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, approximation, multiple-integral

Has anybody seen  a version of the saddle point method for a real-value multivariate function with multiple local minima ?

For a real-value function with a single variable which has a unique minimum the approximation result is usually presented as follow.

We want to approximate a integral of the form $I_\alpha = \int_\mathbb{R}e^{-f_\alpha (x)dx}$ where $f_\alpha$ is twice differentiable. For every $f_\alpha$, $f_\alpha$ has a unique minimum reached at $x_\alpha$. As $\alpha$ goes to $\infty$, $f_\alpha$ is more localised around $x_\alpha$:
$$
\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}(x_\alpha) \xrightarrow[\alpha \rightarrow \infty]{} + \infty
$$
And we use the approximation:
$$
I_\alpha \approx e^{-m_\alpha} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}(x_\alpha)}}
$$

Thanks

Comment: If you mean Laplace's method, see for instance de Bruijn, *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis*. Under certain assumptions, the integral of $e^{\alpha f(\boldsymbol x)}$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\alpha^{−d/2} e^{\alpha f(0)}$ times the integral of $\exp(\sum a_{i, j} x_i x_j)$, where the exponent is the sum of the second-order terms in the Taylor expansion of $f$ around the maximum point $\boldsymbol x = 0$.

Comment: It's not clear what happens when there are multiple minimums and the function "overlaps" around the minimums: eg for the function $exp(- \frac{x^2}{2})+exp(- \frac{(x-\epsilon)^2}{2})$ where $\epsilon$ is close to $0$.

Comment: Consider the one-dimensional case first. The conditions that you listed are not sufficient. If you take $f_\alpha(x) = \ln(1 + \alpha x^2)$, then the second derivative at $x_\alpha = 0$ is $2 \alpha$ but the integral is not asymptotically equivalent to $\sqrt {\pi/\alpha}$. There are various generalizations of Laplace's method that cover functions that are not of the form $\alpha f(x)$, including functions with coalescing stationary points, but there isn't one general formula ("it's a recipe, not a blueprint").

Comment: thanks, the Bruijn seems to be focused on complex analysis.

Comment: For those interested, you can one recipe p71 of the Bruijn.