# Approximations to High Dimensional Integrals

Tags: multiple-integral, gaussian-integral, approximate-integration, laplace-method

Is there a general method for analytically approximating integrals of the form
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} d^{n}\textbf{x} \, \exp(- F_n(\textbf{x})),$$
where $\textbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$,  $F_n(\textbf{x})$ is a function of $\textbf{x}$ indexed by $n$, and $n \gg 1$?

I realize this question or one like it has been asked many times before (see below references), but here I have a concrete example which motivates a particular approach.

**Context/Example**

Laplace's method seems to be a naive possible approach but it results in large errors. For example, take the integral
$$ I_n =  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} d^{n}\textbf{x} \, e^{-\textbf{x}^2/2}\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\Big)^n \prod_{j=1}^n x_j\equiv\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} d^{n}\textbf{x} \, \exp(- F_n(\textbf{x})) $$
If we use Laplace's method, we take $$F_n(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{x}^2/2 - \sum_{j=1}^n \ln x_j - n \ln \sum_{j=1}^n x_j,$$
and solving for $\{\bar{x}_j\}$ such that $\partial_{j} F_n(\bar{\textbf{x}}) = 0$, we find $\bar{x}_j = \sqrt{2}$ for all $j$. Which yields
$$I_n \simeq c_n \exp(-F_n(\bar{\textbf{x}})) = c_n\,2^n \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n,$$
where $c_n$ is some $n$ dependent constant. This result makes sense because one can show that $I_n = n!$ and Stirling's approximation gives $n! \simeq \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n$. The problem comes when one tries to use the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method#Other_formulations) to determine the $c_n$. The value one *should* find is $c_n = \sqrt{2\pi n}/2^n$ but one actually gets something quite different (I got $c_n = \sqrt{3/4}(2/3)^{n/2}$ ) which suggests that the $(n/e)^n$ factor derived from $F_n(\bar{\textbf{x}})$ is only coincidentally correct. Thus Laplace's method isn't the correct approach. Or maybe it is that Laplace's method should be applied in a special way? I'm looking for guidance either way.

Possibly relevant literature reference

- Shun, Zhenming, and Peter McCullagh. "Laplace approximation of high dimensional integrals." *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Methodological)* 57.4 (1995): 749-760. ([http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~pmcc/pubs/paper26.pdf](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Epmcc/pubs/paper26.pdf))

Possibly relevant Stackexchange posts

- [Using the Saddle point method (or Laplace method) for a multiple integral over a large number of variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716380/using-the-saddle-point-method-or-laplace-method-for-a-multiple-integral-over-a)
- [The saddle point method for a real-value multivariate function with several minimal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308110/the-saddle-point-method-for-a-real-value-multivariate-function-with-several-mini)
- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318890/steepest-descent-integration-in-several-dimensions
- [Method of Steepest Descent in the limit of infinite dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361334/method-of-steepest-descent-in-the-limit-of-infinite-dimensions)

Comment: Just how large is $n$ in the applications you are interested in? Or is this a more theoretical question and you are actually considering the case of $n \to \infty$? Just curious

Comment: @YuriyS I'm considering $n$ on the order of $10^2$ and $10^4$. It is more of a theoretical question though, and it would be great if the approach worked for arbitrarily large $n$.